# Stencyl game output, HTML5 or Flash player

Tags: javascript, html, flash, stencyl

i'm making a little web game for work, first time using Stencyl. No mobile support needed, it's a desktop only web game. Stencyl doesn't let me publish to HTML5 though, so I tried doing it old-school, exporting a .swf, but this isn't ideal either because of scalability & such. I'm no HTML wizzkid, so just looking if someone knows how to export to HTML from Stencyl, and otherwise an alternative. Many thanks, friends :)